# vtkTypeTraits.h error: "Type long is not 4 or 8 bytes in size."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, vtk

I am facing a problem compiling a project in Visual Studio 2013 with VTK 7.1.0 (Release, x64).

When I build the project, I get the error below in vtkTypeTraits.h file:

> Error 71  error C1189: #error :  "Type long is not 4 or 8 bytes in
>   size."    ..\vtk-7.1.0\common\core\vtkTypeTraits.h    115 1

The code corresponding to these lines is:

```
#ifndef vtkTypeTraits_h
#define vtkTypeTraits_h

#include "vtkSystemIncludes.h"
#include "vtkType.h"

 ............

// Define traits for long types.
#define VTK_TYPE_NAME_LONG long
#define VTK_TYPE_NAME_UNSIGNED_LONG unsigned long
#if VTK_SIZEOF_LONG == 4
# define VTK_TYPE_SIZED_LONG INT32
# define VTK_TYPE_SIZED_UNSIGNED_LONG UINT32
VTK_TYPE_TRAITS(long, LONG, 1, Int32, long, "%ld");
VTK_TYPE_TRAITS(unsigned long, UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, UInt32, unsigned long, "%lu");
#elif VTK_SIZEOF_LONG == 8
# define VTK_TYPE_SIZED_LONG INT64
# define VTK_TYPE_SIZED_UNSIGNED_LONG UINT64
VTK_TYPE_TRAITS(long, LONG, 1, Int64, long, "%ld");
VTK_TYPE_TRAITS(unsigned long, UNSIGNED_LONG, 0, UInt64, unsigned long, "%lu");
#else
# error "Type long is not 4 or 8 bytes in size." 
#endif
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you find out what `VTK_SIZEOF_LONG` actually is?

Comment: No, I can't. When I am trying to display its value I get nothing.

Comment: It sounds like you're not pulling in `vtkType.h`.  Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE] -- or at least show your `#include` statements.

Comment: Potentially looks like a build setup could be the culprit. `VTK_SIZEOF_LONG` should define to  `KWIML_ABI_SIZEOF_LONG`. KWIML library looks like it has some auto header generation going on. All I can really suggest is to check that `'Common/Core/vtkType.h'` is being included and follow the chain from there up through `vtk_kwiml.h`

Comment: @djgandy Thank you for your help. I have also `#include`d the  `vtk_kwiml.h` file, and the `abi.h` and `int.h` files, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `VTK_SIZEOF_LONG` isn't `#define`d.
You can't define it as `#define VTK_SIZEOF_LONG sizeof(long)` because `sizeof()` won't be evaluated during preprocessing.

I expect you need to `#include` a master configuration file that defines this and any other `_SIZEOF_` macros for your platform for VTK to conditionally compile itself correctly.

On any modern platform this is likely to be 4 or 8 as is implied.

Comment: thank you for your help! Do you know any file that includes _SIZEOF_ macros except from vtkType.h?

Comment: @MariaTsourma If you look in vtkType.h you'll find those values defined in terms of other values that lead back to `abi.h`. `abi.h` looks at some platform #defines which you might need to define in your project or provide in the command-line so the right definitions get picked up.... https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Utilities/KWIML/vtkkwiml/include/kwiml/abi.h

Comment: sorry for asking again, but I have included both `vtkType.h` and `abi.h', and also `vtk_kwiml.h` in case I am missing something. The problem is still the same. Am I doing something wrong with the `#include`s?